# UIImagePickerController Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, overlay, uiimagepickercontroller

I am creating an `UIImagePickerController` for a full screen camera **using a custom OverLayView** but when ever I rotate my device I get an error saying "`CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.`" As a reference to how I am going about doing this I am following this tutorial: http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code to rotate the overlay view of camera

```
cameraOverlayView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-3.141592/2);
```

and it's for scale transform:

```
cameraController.cameraViewTransform=CGAffineTransformScale(cameraController.cameraViewTransform, 1, 1.25);
```